# Changing the Log level in this script

Tags: python, logging, serversocket

I am using the script from [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577025-loggingwebmonitor-a-central-logging-server-and-mon/) source.I want to change the log level of what the web server is displaying to only have `ERROR` logs displayed.
In the line 371 i have made the change

`'rootLogger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)'`

but I still have Debug and Info messages in the web page.Can someone have a look and tell me what I am doing wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: So if you run the test script from that linked page, you're seeing all four log messages?

Comment: Yes. What I want to make is to have on the web only the logs that are above Error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at line 136 it says that everything will get logged and that you should set levels client side.

Maybe you should set the level in the clientcode as is shown below the code block.